# How to draw line with in a image not whole UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer, cashapelayer

Before Colouring the image:

[image]

After Colouring the Image:

[image]

This is my code :

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.imgColor];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingPoint.x,startingPoint.y)];
    startingPoint=touchPoint;
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [self.imgColor.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    [arrLayer addObject:shapeLayer];
    NSLog(@"Touch moving point =x : %f Touch moving point =y : %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);  
}
```

Depend upon the user touch, it's drawing a line inside `UIImageView`.

**What i need is :**

If image size is to small, then I don't like to allow draw outside the image.

Within the image user have to draw ,is there any way? Please suggest me.

Comment: Simplest way is stop the line when `if (!CGRectContainsPoint(doggyImage.frame, touchPoint))`

Comment: ok @zcui93 i try your point ...

Comment: no @zcui93 my UIImageView frame is big ,but the dog image is small ,i like to color only inside the dog image .

Comment: The code suggested only prevent the line drawing from inside to outside. The idea is to check whether the touch point is inside your dog image or not. You need to do some similar check to not start drawing when `touchStart`.

Comment: can you suggest some more code deep about it @zcui93

Comment: this is what i tried @zcui93      if (!CGRectContainsPoint(_imgColor.frame, touchPoint))
    {
        [self.imgColor.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
        [arrLayer addObject:shapeLayer];

    }
    else
    {
        
    }

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your touch handing view.

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    return CGRectContainsPoint(doggyImage.frame, point)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code provided in the first comment `if (!CGRectContainsPoint(doggyImage.frame, touchPoint))` is some condition that you can use to check whether the touch point is in one specific view, where I think you should use to compare with your dog image (I don't know which variable it is, so I used `doggyImage`. Maybe `self.imgColor` is the correct one or not).

And for simplest solution, you need to do at least two things

- If `touchesBegan` outside the `doggyImage`, don't do anything, just `return`.
- Prevent lines been draw from inside to outside, so use the same condition, and apply the same code you used in `touchesEnd` to handle something like `stopDrawLine`.

More advanced method would include computing the nearest point from the touch to the image if it's outside, and draw it on the edge.

BTW, currently in your `touchesMoved`, you created one new `UIBezierPath` every single touch point, resulting in hundreds of discrete small pieces of line. You may want to try to new a `path` when `touchesBegan` and `addLineToPoint` in `touchesMoved`. So that the whole line is in one path, and you can therefore offer freatures like "undo".

Answer (score 0):

take one CGRect object Globally assign its value as follow

```
 CGRect imagerect = CGRectMake(imgColor.center.x - (imgColor.image.size.width/2 + imgColor.frame.origin.x), imgColor.center.y - (imgColor.image.size.height/2+ imgColor.frame.origin.y), imgColor.image.size.width, imgColor.image.size.height);
```

now in `touchesMoved` method put one condition before drawing  `if( CGRectContainsPoint(imagerect, touchPoint))`

so the method will be like

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
      touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.imgColor];


    if( CGRectContainsPoint(imagerect, touchPoint))
    {

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingPoint.x,startingPoint.y)];
    startingPoint=touchPoint;
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [self.imgColor.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    [arrLayer addObject:shapeLayer];
    NSLog(@"Touch moving point =x : %f Touch moving point =y : %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
    }

}
```

Comment: jay thanks for the answer but your code only work for rectangular image not for all image ,in my case image should be differ .like circle ,rect,eclipse .

Comment: I have added new answer please check.  i have not edited it because if someone want draw in  rectangular image then they will use this code

Comment: @jey after add layer how can i create new edited image from it and save or send it.

Comment: @HardikVyas it's too old hope below code work for you

``` - (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    if (_videoURL)
    {
        [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    } else
    {
        [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    }
    
    //
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}```
you have to create image from your view

Answer (score 0):

Might be this is not perfect solution but i try to make same as your requirements. please try with this

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    CGPoint touchPoint,startingPoint;

    CALayer *layer;
    float x1;
    float y1;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imgColor;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    layer = [CALayer layer];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    CGSize scaledImageSize = imgColor.image.size;
    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(roundf(0.5f*(CGRectGetWidth(imgColor.bounds)-scaledImageSize.width)), roundf(0.5f*(CGRectGetHeight(imgColor.bounds)-scaledImageSize.height)), roundf(scaledImageSize.width), roundf(scaledImageSize.height));
    x1 = imageFrame.origin.x ;
    y1 =  imageFrame.origin.y ;


}



- (UIColor*)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)x andY:(int)y
{
    if (x < 0 || y<0  || x> image.size.width || y > image.size.height) {
        return nil;
    }
    // First get the image into your data buffer
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = (unsigned char*) calloc(height * width * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    NSUInteger byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * y) + x * bytesPerPixel;

        CGFloat alpha = ((CGFloat) rawData[byteIndex + 3] ) / 255.0f;
        CGFloat red   = ((CGFloat) rawData[byteIndex]     ) / alpha;
        CGFloat green = ((CGFloat) rawData[byteIndex + 1] ) / alpha;
        CGFloat blue  = ((CGFloat) rawData[byteIndex + 2] ) / alpha;
        byteIndex += bytesPerPixel;
    if (red >= 0 || green >= 0 || blue >= 0) {
        return  [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:alpha];

    }
    return nil;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    touchPoint = [touch locationInView:imgColor];

    ;
    if ([self getRGBAsFromImage:imgColor.image atX:touchPoint.x - x1 andY:touchPoint.y - y1] && !(touchPoint.x == 0 && touchPoint.y == 0)) {

    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingPoint.x,startingPoint.y)];
    startingPoint=touchPoint;
    CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];


        [imgColor.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    }

}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event;
{
    touchPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
}
@end
```